# Tensorboard Graphs: Coloring by {Compute time, Memory} is not enabled

Tags: tensorboard

On the Tensorboard Graphs tab for both the Compute time and the Memory radio buttons I see the error:

```
"Coloring by {Compute time, Memory} is only enabled if the RunMetadata proto is passed to the FileWriter when a specific session is run"
```

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.log_dir + '\\test')
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

feed_dict = {
test_data_node: image,
test_labels_node: label,
phase_train: False
}

dense_prediction, im = sess.run([logits, pred], feed_dict=feed_dict, options = run_options, run_metadata = run_metadata)
writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'run')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows with GTX 1070.  I setup run_metadata and pass it to run but somehow it still doesn't work in Tensorboard.  I was able to see the timeline data when I explicitly saved it out myself.  

Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Same problem here on Windows with RTX 2080. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No and no. Sorry.